# Is a salary of 35000 pounds enough for a couple to live comfortably in Portsmouth, UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental, salary, cost-of-living

Expecting to move to the UK soon.

Comment: Welcome to Expats.SE. Please take a look at our [help]. We are different from many discussion forums in that we focus on questions that have answers. What is comfortable for me may not be comfortable for you, so we need a more concrete question.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a subjective question.

You can find out the cost of living using a few websites:

Rightmove.co.uk for accommodation

Tesco.co.uk to get an idea of cost of groceries

moneysavingexpert.com/tax-calculator to find your post-tax salary